# Transform canvas to image using toDataURL() and add to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I implement:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

Both are the latest versions.
I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#down_but').click(function() {
            html2canvas(document.getElementById("node")).then(canvas => {
                const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1);
                const pdf = new jsPDF();
                pdf.addImage(img,"jpeg",5,5,205,292);
                pdf.save("file.pdf");

            });
        });
    });
```

When I just put some text and no addImage to pdf, pdf opens and download. But when i use canvas toDataurl nothing happend. I really don't know why. I try copy and paste code from another questions but none of them works for me.
When I click on download button with id="down_but" it just give error in dev console.

[See console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFioH.png)

I try anything but nothing help. Please help me if someone know where is problem.
I create [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9nmbpfj/12/) for it too.

Comment: you have syntax error inside your fiddle

Comment: @Muath Can I ask where? I just check it and i don't know where

Comment: when i run the fiddle i didnt get the error you asked about i got this:
Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined

Comment: just changed the library url https://jsfiddle.net/cpL5qt72/
is this what you need??

Comment: @Muath Thanks man! it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add last version of [html2canvas.js](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js)

```
https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cpL5qt72/)